# I'm trying to write a SQL statement in VBA to concatenate first and last name

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm getting errors.

```
SELECT [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position
FROM TblMembers
WHERE (((TblMembers.Position)="Lt #1"));
```

This is the original....

```
SQL = "SELECT [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position
       FROM TblMembers
       WHERE (((TblMembers.Position)="Lt #1"));"
```

I'm exporting names to excel files and have several files, don't want to make queries for each one, so would like to extract the data on open.

Here is my full code, corrected as below.

```
Private Sub Cmdtestopen_Click()


On Error GoTo SubError

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset


    SQL = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE TblMembers.Position='Lt #1' "


    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)


    If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data selected for export", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No data exported"
        GoTo SubExit
    End If


    Set xlApp = Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

    With xlSheet
        .Name = "Discount"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 11


        Do While Not rs1.EOF

            .Range("A1").Value = Nz(rs1!FullName, "")


            rs1.MoveNext

        Loop


    End With


SubExit:
On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    xlApp.Visible = True
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing

    Exit Sub

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "= " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "An error occurred"
    GoTo SubExit


End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  It's best to show a little more context by including more of your code: it's not clear exactly what's going on here...

Comment: syntax errors.  I found I needed the & _ but got them all wrong.

Comment: I need to open this file vs open a new excel instance.  I get miss match errors when I  use this                                                                         Set wbTarget1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Trk_Insp_1204_10_08_2016.xlsx")                                        vs this                                      Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Comment: I've fixed the code block in the last revision, but if "corrected as per below" means that code is your working code and you'd like thank @TimWilliams for his answer, know that the correct way to do this on this site, is to click the green hollow checkmark next to his answer, so as to mark the question as "answered". The actual working code is irrelevant to the question, please remove it if the current state of the question has no specific question to be answered; also note, "chameleon questions" are frowned upon.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was asked to show more of the code that led to the question, so I added that to the original question as asked.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by chameleon questions, but will refrain from doing that in the future.  Do you mean the question about the excel file... if so, yes I'll not do that in the future, was just going to expound on the theme i.e. the code I'm working on.  Is it better to ask another question then.  My first time asking questions. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes delimit a `String` literal. To have double quotes *inside* a `String` literal you need to "escape" them; in VBA the way to do this is to double-up the double quotes:

```
SQL = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.Position " & _
      " FROM TblMembers " & _
      " WHERE TblMembers.Position='Lt #1' "
```

Comment: Please explain to OP and future readers your specific changes. Code only answers are not recommended. And why double quotes between first and last names, just keep consistent like the single quotes in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Parfait because double quote is the way to actually send a literal quote.

Comment: Depending on the driver, I thought you could also do "... [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]..."